# Error with catkin build with ds4_driver

Tags: ros, catkin, motoman, ros-kinetic, joystick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone please help me solve the following error I get when running catkin build?

```
Error: Attempting to build a catkin workspace using build space: "/home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/build" but that build space's most recent configuration differs from the commanded one in ways which will cause problems. Fix the following options or use `catkin clean -b` to remove the build space:  - install: False (stored) is not True (commanded)
```

For context, I have been trying to enable the [ds4_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/ds4_driver) for joystick control. To set this up, I have been referencing 1) [ds4_driver](http://wiki.ros.org/ds4_driver), 2) [A Sony DualShock 4 userspace driver for Linux](https://github.com/naoki-mizuno/ds4drv), and 3) [Using a PlayStation DS4 with ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04](http://ben.bongalon.com/using-a-playstation-ds4-with-ros-kinetic-on-ubuntu-16-04).

Speciffically, following the installation instructions in [Using a PlayStation DS4 with ROS Kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04](http://ben.bongalon.com/using-a-playstation-ds4-with-ros-kinetic-on-ubuntu-16-04), in step 2 when the `$ catkin_make` command is run,

```
The build space at '/home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/build' was previously built by 'catkin build'. Please remove the build space or pick a different build space.
```

This makes sense, I have gotten this in the past for other programs so generally run `$ catkin build` instead. However, now when I run `$catkin build`, I get:

```
Error: Attempting to build a catkin workspace using build space: "/home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/build" but that build space's most recent configuration differs from the commanded one in ways which will cause problems. Fix the following options or use `catkin clean -b` to remove the build space:   - install: False (stored) is not True (commanded)
```

Running `$ catkin build --dry-run` I get the following:

```
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ catkin build --dry-run
-------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:        [explicit] /opt/ros/kinetic
Workspace:                   /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2
-------------------------------------------------------------
Build Space:        [exists] /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/devel
Install Space:     [missing] /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/install
Log Space:          [exists] /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/logs
Source Space:       [exists] /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/src
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        merged
-------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       None
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
-------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.
-------------------------------------------------------------
[build] Found '73' packages in 0.0 seconds.                                    
Packages to be built:
- control_msgs                    (catkin)
- controller_manager_msgs         (catkin)
- hardware_interface              (catkin)
- combined_robot_hw               (catkin)
- controller_interface            (catkin)
- controller_manager              (catkin)
- controller_manager_tests        (catkin)
- combined_robot_hw_tests         (catkin)
- industrial_core                 (metapackage)
- industrial_deprecated           (catkin)
- industrial_msgs                 (catkin)
- industrial_robot_simulator      (catkin)
- industrial_trajectory_filters   (catkin)
- industrial_utils                (catkin)
- joint_limits_interface          (catkin)
- motoman                         (metapackage)
- motoman_gp12_support            (catkin)
- motoman_gp7_support             (catkin)
- motoman_gp8_support             (catkin)
- motoman_gp8_urdf                (catkin)
- motoman_mh12_support            (catkin)
- motoman_mh50_support            (catkin)
- motoman_mh5_support             (catkin)
- motoman_motomini_support        (catkin)
- motoman_msgs                    (catkin)
- motoman_sda10f_moveit_config    (catkin)
- motoman_sda10f_support          (catkin)
- motoman_sia10d_support          (catkin)
- motoman_sia10f_support          (catkin)
- motoman_sia20d_moveit_config    (catkin)
- motoman_sia20d_support          (catkin)
- motoman_sia5d_support           (catkin)
- realtime_tools                  (catkin)
- control_toolbox                 (catkin)
- diff_drive_controller           (catkin)
- ackermann_steering_controller   (catkin)
- force_torque_sensor_controller  (catkin)
- forward_command_controller      (catkin)
- effort_controllers              (catkin)
- gripper_action_controller       (catkin)
- imu_sensor_controller           (catkin)
- joint_state_controller          (catkin)
- joint_trajectory_controller     (catkin)
- position_controllers            (catkin)
- ros_control                     (metapackage)
- ros_controllers                 (metapackage)
- rosserial                       (metapackage)
- rosserial_arduino               (catkin)
- rosserial_mbed                  (catkin)
- rosserial_msgs                  (catkin)
- rosserial_client                (catkin)
- rosserial_embeddedlinux         (catkin)
- rosserial_python                (catkin)
- rosserial_server                (catkin)
- rosserial_test                  (catkin)
- rosserial_tivac                 (catkin)
- rosserial_vex_cortex            (catkin)
- rosserial_vex_v5                (catkin)
- rosserial_windows               (catkin)
- rosserial_xbee                  (catkin)
- rqt_controller_manager          (catkin)
- rqt_joint_trajectory_controller (catkin)
- simple_message                  (catkin)
- industrial_robot_client         (catkin)
- motoman_driver                  (catkin)
- gp8_moveit_config               (catkin)
- motoman_gp8_moveit_config       (catkin)
- transmission_interface          (catkin)
- velocity_controllers            (catkin)
- vrep_common                     (catkin)
- vrep_plugin                     (catkin)
- warehouse_ros                   (catkin)
- warehouse_ros_mongo             (catkin)
Total packages: 73
```

and running `$ catkin config` I get

```
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ catkin config
-------------------------------------------------------------
Profile:                     default
Extending:        [explicit] /opt/ros/kinetic
Workspace:                   /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2
-------------------------------------------------------------
Build Space:        [exists] /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/build
Devel Space:        [exists] /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/devel
Install Space:     [missing] /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/install
Log Space:          [exists] /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/logs
Source Space:       [exists] /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/src
DESTDIR:            [unused] None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Devel Space Layout:          linked
Install Space Layout:        merged
-------------------------------------------------------------
Additional CMake Args:       None
Additional Make Args:        None
Additional catkin Make Args: None
Internal Make Job Server:    True
Cache Job Environments:      False
-------------------------------------------------------------
Whitelisted Packages:        None
Blacklisted Packages:        None
-------------------------------------------------------------
Workspace configuration appears valid.
```

Can anyone please offer some suggestions?

Thank you in advance for all your help with this!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353143/error-with-catkin-build-with-ds4_driver/) by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-24

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-25**:
Off-topic, but: seeing as you're running Kinetic: do you really need to build all those packages from source?

All the `industrial_*` packages have binaries available for Kinetic (on Ubuntu Xenial), so do the `rosserial` and `ros_control` packages. Of course, if you prefer some version of `ros_control(lers)` which hasn't been released for Kinetic, a from-source build makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Can anyone please offer some suggestions?

Run `catkin clean -y` in the root of your workspace, then run `catkin build`.

As the error message tells you, mixing the two tools for building the same workspace is unsupported.

So remove the `build` and `devel` directories (which the `catkin clean -y` command will do), choose one of the two tools (either `catkin_make` or `catkin_tools`) and then build the workspace.

---

Edit: in the end it turned out the OP had Catkin configured to create an `install` space, but was still `source`-ing the `devel` space.

After disabling the `install` space, cleaning and rebuilding the workspace, things started working again, even after `source devel/setup.bash`.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-05-26**:
Thank you @gvdhoorn, except now I am getting the following error

```
[robot_interface_streaming_yrc1000.launch] is neither a launch file in package [motoman_driver] nor is [motoman_driver] a launch file name The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Looking to the launch folder, the launch file is there in the launch folder of the motoman_driver folder. What did I do wrong? I also saved a copy of my catkin_ws (before the catkin clean) on an external hd if we need to go back to it. What are your thoughts? Thank you for all your help with this gvdhoorn!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-27**:
So you remove all the `build` and `devel` directories from your workspace (essentially you only keep `src`), then `source /opt/ros/kinetic/setup.bash`, then run `catkin build`, wait, and then finally `source devel/setup.bash`?

At this point, `rospack find motoman_driver` returns the directory in your `src` space. Correct?

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-05-27**:
@gvdhoorn, that is correct.

I shell 1 I input and receive the following:

```
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws2/
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ ls -1
build
devel
install
logs
src
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ catkin clean -y
[clean] Removing installspace: /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/install
[clean] Removing develspace: /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/devel
[clean] Removing buildspace: /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/build
[clean] Removing log space: /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/logs
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ printenv | grep ROS
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_VERSION=1
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
```

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-05-27**:
Then in shell 1 I input

```
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ catkin build
```

and receive (only showing the tail due to character count)

```
[build] Summary: All 69 packages succeeded!                                             
[build]   Ignored:   5 packages were skipped or are blacklisted.                        
[build]   Warnings:  14 packages succeeded with warnings.                               
[build]   Abandoned: None.                                                              
[build]   Failed:    None.                                                              
[build] Runtime: 5 minutes and 16.8 seconds total.                                      
[build] Note: Workspace packages have changed, please re-source setup files to use them.
```

then in shell 1 I input in receive

```
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ ls
build  devel  install  logs  src
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ source devel/setup.bash
```

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-05-27**:
Finally in shell 1 I input

```
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ gedit ~/.bashrc
```

In shell 2 input

```
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws2/
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ source ~/catkin_ws2/devel/setup.bash
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ roscore
```

to start roscore, and receive the usual output.

Then, in shell 3, set the joint names

Then  shell 4 input and receive the following

```
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~$ cd ~/catkin_ws2/
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ source ~/catkin_ws2/devel/setup.bash
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ roslaunch motoman_driver robot_interface_streaming_yrc1000.launch robot_ip:=192.168.0.145
[robot_interface_streaming_yrc1000.launch] is neither a launch file in package [motoman_driver] nor is [motoman_driver] a launch file name The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Thank you again for all your help with this gvdhoorn!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-27**:
High-level question: why are you starting `robot_interface_streaming_yrc1000.launch` directly, instead of via one of the `.launch` files in one of the robot support packages? "Setting the joint names" is not something you typically do manually either.

You may have a setup which requires this, but as-is, the statement confuses me.

As to "shell 4", try this (in the same shell, after having run `source ~/catkin_ws2/devel/setup.bash`:

```
rospack profile
rospack find motoman_driver
```

Does the last command print an error, or return a path?

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-05-27**:
w.r.t the first question, no specific reason. This is just the way that I had had it running prior. I will try the .launch file after we get operational again.
w.r.t the second question. I get the following when inputting and receiving in shell 4:

```
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ rospack profile
Full tree crawl took 0.018645 seconds.
Directories marked with (*) contain no manifest.  You may
want to delete these directories.
To get just of list of directories without manifests,re-run the profile with --zombie-only
-------------------------------------------------------------
0.017855   /opt/ros/kinetic/share
0.000187 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev
0.000048 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/man
0.000039 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev/haarcascades
0.000030 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/doc
0.000015 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/OpenCV-3.3.1-dev/lbpcascades
0.000010 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/man/man1
0.000005 * /opt/ros/kinetic/share/doc/liborocos-kdl
```

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-05-27**:
and this when inputting and receiving in shell 4

```
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ rospack find motoman_driver
[rospack] Error: package 'motoman_driver' not found
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-27**:
what is the output of `env | grep -i ros | sort` in "shell 4" (again, after having run `source ~/catkin_ws2/devel/setup.bash`)?

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-05-27**:
shell 4 shows

```
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ env | grep -i ros | sort
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic:/home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/devel
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu:/home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/devel/lib
PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/bin:/home/bdelspi/bin:/home/bdelspi/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/opt/V-REP_PRO_EDU_V3_6_2_Ubuntu16_04
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/pkgconfig:/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/pkgconfig:/home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/devel/lib/pkgconfig
PYTHONPATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages:/home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/devel/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
ROS_DISTRO=kinetic
ROS_ETC_DIR=/opt/ros/kinetic/etc/ros
ROSLISP_PACKAGE_DIRECTORIES=
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/opt/ros/kinetic/share
ROS_ROOT=/opt/ros/kinetic/share/ros
ROS_VERSION=1
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-27**:
Ah, I believe I understand what is going on: you have Catkin configured to *install* your packages into an `install` space:

```
Install Space:     [missing] /home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/install
```

(it says "missing", as it creates that directory as part of a `catkin build`).

So instead of `source ~/catkin_ws2/devel/setup.bash`, you should run:

```
source ~/catkin_ws2/install/setup.bash
```

If you do that, I expect `rospack find motoman_driver` to no longer error out, but to print a path.

Could you verify?

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-05-27**:
@gvdhoorn that makes sense, the `install space` is new (i.e it did not exist in my `catkin_ws2)` prior, I only had `devel`, `build`, `src`, and `logs` folders under the `catkin_ws2` folder.

Two questions

1. Should I open a new terminal (i.e shell 5) to run `source ~/catkin_ws2/install/setup.bash`and then `rospack find motoman_driver`? or stay in shell 4 to run them?
2. Is there a way for us to get it back to the original format (i.e `build`, `devel`, `logs`, and `src` folders under `catkin_ws2`)? or is the the 5 folder system the convention? The 4 folder system (with `source ~/catkin_ws2/devel/setup.bash`) is what I have written our SOPs for...

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-27**:
Run everything in "shell 4". You don't need to start any new ones.

As to your second question: let's first diagnose what is going on. Only after we've found the cause of your problems we can start thinking about other approaches.

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-05-27**:
@gvdhoorn that makes sense.

You are awesome! Yes, running `source ~/catkin_ws2/install/setup.bash` and then `rospack find motoman_driver` in shell 4 we get the following:

```
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ source ~/catkin_ws2/install/setup.bash
bdelspi@bdelspi-Latitude-E5550:~/catkin_ws2$ rospack find motoman_driver
/home/bdelspi/catkin_ws2/install/share/motoman_driver
```

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-05-27**:
What are your thoughts moving forward? How should we proceed? Thank you again for your help with this @gvdhoorn!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-27**:
To get "back to your previous configuration", do this:

```
catkin config --no-install
catkin clean -y
catkin build
```

after this completes, you should be able to `source ~/catkin_ws2/devel/setup.bash` again and things should work.

As to how you got into this situation: I wouldn't know. To make Catkin install everything, you need to run `catkin config --install` deliberately. This does not happen by itself.

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-05-27**:
@gvdhoorn strange, not sure how that could of happend, even looking to my OP I only ever ran `catkin config`.

Testing the system now and will get back shortly with the results. Thank you again for all your help with this gvdhoorn, I can not say that enough, you are awesome!

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-05-27**:
@gvdhoorn, do you prefer robot guru or robot whisperer? You are awesome! We are fully operational again, thank you so much for all your help with this gvdhoorn!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-05-27**:
It's really just a build tool, but glad to hear you got things sorted out.

Don't forget to take a look at how you start the driver.

Refer to [wiki/Working with ROS-Industrial Robot Support Packages](http://wiki.ros.org/Industrial/Tutorials/WorkingWithRosIndustrialRobotSupportPackages) for an intro on how to use robot support packages correctly.

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-05-27**:
Absolutely, will do gvdhoorn and will post back here. Thank you for all your help and patience with me as I learn through this! Super powerful, super cool, and I am looking forward to learning more! Thank you again gvdhoorn!

**Comment by [bdelspi](https://answers.ros.org/users/55211/bdelspi/) on 2020-07-09**:
@gvdhoorn, first and foremost, thank you again for all your help on the above challenge! Following up on the question "why are you starting robot_interface_streaming_yrc1000.launch directly, instead of via one of the .launch files in one of the robot support packages? "Setting the joint names" is not something you typically do manually either." I went back through my notes and remembered I did so from following the [Using the Motoman FS/DX/YRC ROS Interface](http://wiki.ros.org/motoman_driver/Tutorials/Usage) tutorial. Specifically Section 2 Usage (and subsequently Section 2.1 Joint Naming). There it goes on to state "Most motoman robots use joint names that differ from the ROS-I "standard" joint names ([joint_1, joint_2, ..., joint_N])." and describes the procedure. Did I do something wrong? Is there a better way to do this? Thank you again for all your help and patience with me through this as I learn gvdhoorn!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-07-14**:
The robots using different joint names does not say anything about *how* those joint names should end up on the parameter server.

As the wiki pages show, and the other support packages provide examples of, you typically want to use a `.launch` file specific to your robot variant and controller to configure all of this.

I'd recommend to take a look at some of the other support packages for Motoman robots and copy their structure.

Don't start the generic `robot_interface_streaming_XXXX.launch` directly. Use a per-robot (or per-workcell) `.launch` file for that.